# AgGrid Angular Column Change Detection to reflect all rows

Tags: ag-grid-angular

Ag Grid Angular : Consider we have 5 rows and 3 column (1editable) in each row. If I change the value of editable column in row 1 all other row's editable column will be set as blank. Please assist how I can implement this?

Comment: Can you show some code of hat you already tried to do?

Comment: @Nino Filiu Sorry can't share any code snippet. Please let me know if you want any clarification on the requirement.

Comment: The thing is, people on stack overflow can't help with your code if you don't provide any. So please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)